# mysql select from n last rows

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

I have a table with index (autoincrement) and integer value. The table is millions of rows long.

How can I search if a certain number appear in the last n rows of the table most efficiently?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Starting from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows/573665#573665) given by @chaos, but with a few modifications:

- You should always use `ORDER BY` if you use `LIMIT`.  There is no implicit order guaranteed for an RDBMS table.  You may *usually* get rows in the order of the primary key, but you can't rely on this, nor is it portable.
- If you order by in the descending order, you don't need to know the number of rows in the table beforehand.
- You must give a *correlation name* (aka table alias) to a derived table.

Here's my version of the query:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (
    SELECT `id`, `val`
    FROM `big_table`
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT $n
) AS t
WHERE t.`val` = $certain_number;
```

Comment: I would upvote this several times if I could, all the other answers are buggy. This is what I would've posted too.

Comment: Note that the answer from @chaos to which I refer has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks! How many records will the engine have to scan to get the answer? Is it n? or m= the location of val from the top?

Comment: I assume it would have to scan only n rows.  The ORDER BY...LIMIT can be done using an index, without scanning rows.

Comment: @BillKarwin what should `$certain_number` be? `$n` is obviously the size of the result. Then I would up vote this

Comment: @JSHelp, the OP asks how to check if a *certain number* appears in the last *n* rows. So `$certain_number` is the value that the OP is searching for. `$n` is not the size of the result, it's the number of rows to search. The size of the result may be just one, if `val` is a unique column, or it could be up to `$n`, or it could be zero rows if the value is not found.

Comment: @BillKarwin got it. I have found, what I have been searching for [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql)

Answer (score 20):

Might be a very late answer, but this is good and simple.

```
select * from table_name order by id desc limit 5
```

This query will return a set of last 5 values(last 5 rows) you 've inserted in your table

Comment: What value does this provide? The question was answered six years ago. The code snippet appears to be a subset of previously provided answers, and it has not explanation.

Answer (score 14):

Last 5 rows retrieve in mysql

This query working perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM recharge ORDER BY sno DESC LIMIT 5)sub ORDER BY sno ASC
```

or

```
select sno from(select sno from recharge order by sno desc limit 5) as t where t.sno order by t.sno asc
```

Answer (score 13):

Take advantage of SORT and LIMIT as you would with pagination. If you want the ith block of rows, use OFFSET.

```
SELECT val FROM big_table
where val = someval
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT n;
```

In response to Nir:
The sort operation is not necessarily penalized, this depends on what the query planner does. Since this use case is crucial for pagination performance, there are some optimizations (see link above). This is true in postgres as well "ORDER BY ... LIMIT can be done without sorting " [E.7.1. Last bullet](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/release-8-3.html)

```
explain extended select id from items where val = 48 order by id desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: You can't use MAX() or COUNT() in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Case doesn't strip out NULL's so I removed that example altogether.

Comment: In the current example the db engine will have to look through all n rows even if it finds the value at the first one. Not too omptimized.

Comment: In my non-stringent test, mysql 5.0.x uses an index, as above.

Answer (score 3):

because it is autoincrement, here's my take:

```
Select * from tbl 
where certainconditionshere 
and autoincfield >= (select max(autoincfield) from tbl) - $n
```

Comment: I would just change the order of conditions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This answer assumes the last $n rows have contiguous id values.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a bit old, but try using `PDO::lastInsertId`. I think it does what you want it to, but you would have to rewrite your application to use PDO (Which is a lot safer against attacks)