# Getting the last n results of a MySQL query but in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to do exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows) but I want to do it in Cake PHP which makes things more complicated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$results = $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id), 
                                             'contain' => array('OtherModel' => array('limit' => 10)));
```

which limits the results of data from `OtherModel` to 10.  This isn't quite what I want though.. I want to limit the results to the last 10 results.

Any ideas how you would do this?

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you are on the right track.

Add this to your find parameters:

```
'order' => 'id DESC' // or created or whatever field you want to reverse sort by
```

That combination with `LIMIT` will get the last x results.