# Get the last 2 rows of a table while grouping one of the column. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Consider Facebook. Facebook displays the latest 2 comments of any status. I want to do something similar.

I have a table with e.g. `status_id`, `comment_id`, `comment` and `timestamp`.
Now I want to fetch the latest 2 comments for each `status_id`.

Currently I am first doing a `GROUP_CONCAT` of all columns, group by `status_id` and then taking the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `-2`.

This fetches the latest 2 comments, however the `GROUP_CONCAT` of all the records for a status_id is an overhead.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT('~', comment_id,
                                    '~', comment,
                                    '~', timestamp) 
                        SEPARATOR '|~|'), 
        '|~|', -2)
FROM commenttable
GROUP BY status_id;
```

Can you help me with better approach?

My table looks like this -

status_id comment_id comment timestamp

```
1          1    xyz1     3 hour
1          2    xyz2     2 hour
1          3    xyz3     1 hour
2          4    xyz4     2 hour
2          6    xyz6     1 hour
3          5    xyz5     1 hour
```

So I want the output as -

```
1          2    xyz2     2 hour
1          3    xyz3     1 hour
2          4    xyz4     2 hour
2          6    xyz6     1 hour
3          5    xyz5     1 hour
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle I found this solution -

The following gives me the row_id -

```
  SELECT a.status_id, 
         a.comments_id, 
         COUNT(*) AS row_num 
  FROM comments a
       JOIN comments b 
       ON a.status_id = b.status_id AND a.comments_id >= b.comments_id
  GROUP BY a.status_id , a.comments_id
  ORDER BY row_num DESC
```

The gives me the total rows -

```
SELECT com.status_id, COUNT(*) total 
FROM comments com 
GROUP BY com.status_id
```

In the where clause of the main select -

```
row_num = total OR row_num = total - 1
```

This gives the latest 2 rows. You can modify the where clause to fetch more than 2 latest rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great answer I came across [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/):

```
select status_id, comment_id, comment, timestamp
from commenttable
where (
   select count(*) from commenttable as f
   where f.status_id = commenttable.status_id 
         and f.timestamp < commenttable.timestamp
) <= 2;
```

This is not very efficient (O(n^2)) but it's a lot more efficient than concatenating strings and using substrings to isolate your desired result.  Some would say that reverting to string operations instead of native database indexing robs you of the benefits of using a database in the first place.

Comment: This is not tested, it could have some typos.