# Select last N rows from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to select last 50 rows from MySQL database within column named **id** which is **primary key**. Goal is that the rows should be sorted by **id** in **ASC** order, that’s why this query isn’t working

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Also it’s remarkable that rows could be manipulated (deleted) and that’s why following query isn’t working either

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    id > ((SELECT 
            MAX(id)
        FROM
            chat) - 50)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

**Question**: How is it possible to retrieve last N rows from MySQL database that can be manipulated and be in ASC order ?

Comment: I know that this question is old, but please clarify the data structure of the table and, especially, the id column. Is that an integer? is that a string - that can be sorted? That is not 100% clear and is leading to weird answers trying to help. Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can do it with a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
) AS sub
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

This will select the *last* 50 rows from `table`, and then order them in ascending order.

Comment: ^ FYI, I know this article is about MySQL, but wanted to advise that in response to @DiegoDD's comment above, omitting the external select and alias does not seem to work in Postgres (9.3.5).  I get an 'Error: multiple ORDER BY clauses not allowed'.  The accepted answer, however, does work as expected in Postgres

Comment: Thanks for this! This query helped me fixed my problem. I have been searching for this for hours

Comment: How can I apply this query with JOINS?

Comment: @GYaN add joins in the inner sub query

Comment: What if id is not given then is there a way to do this? Like in oracle we can use rownum fro such situation what can we do in MySQL?

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

save resources make one query, there is no need to make nested queries

Comment: Your query will return the results in reverse (descending id). @newfurniturey's query will get the LAST inserted rows (`LIMIT`ing on descending id), and the final result will have ascending ids.

Comment: Your solution will not get the results in the right order instead it will get them reverses thus the need for another order by to get them in the right order again

Comment: But then you just do a php array_reverse() or whatever the equivalent is in your scripting language of choice. The database doesn't need to do that work.

Comment: @Joe There's nothing in the question that indicates a scripting language is being used, so that's not a safe assumption to make.

Comment: The expected answer should already be sorted using just the database query.

Comment: Nah...you revers the data :). Not correct.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC, datechat DESC LIMIT 50
```

If you have a date field that is storing the date (and time) on which the chat was sent or any field that is filled with incrementally (`order by DESC`) or de-incrementally (`order by ASC`) data per row put it as second column on which the data should be ordered.

That's what worked for me!!!! Hope it will help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use it to retrieve last n rows from mysql

**Select * from tbl order by id desc limit 10;**

use limit according to N value.

Comment: This is identical to two of the three answers, and the OP's actual query. The question isn't only how to get the last 10 rows but how to get them in *ascending* order

Answer (score 0):

if anyone need this
you can change this into

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    id > ((SELECT 
            MAX(id)
        FROM
            chat) - 50)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

**into**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    id > (SELECT MAX(id)- 50 FROM chat) 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from Table ORDER BY id LIMIT 30
```

Notes:
* `id` should be unique.
* You can control the numbers of rows returned by replacing the `30` in the query

Comment: Could you please explain your solution? The explanation in brackets appears to be code, put a whole sentence above/below your code. Thanks