# Mysql query - Search only the latest x rows

Tags: mysql

This is my first question here so I hope im doing it right. I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *, 
  MATCH(name, descr) AGAINST ('$q') AS score 
FROM songs 
WHERE MATCH (name, descr) AGAINST('$q') 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

As you may know, this query selects everything from every row from the `songs` table, if there is a match in the description or in the name .What I want to do,is to limit the query only to search the latest 10k rows for example. I also have a primary key, `id`.

Comment: Just to be sure, you really mean _search_, not _return_ the last 10k rows, right?

Comment: Have you tried adding `LIMIT 10000` after `ORDER BY score DESC`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You will need a nested query. Try this:

```
SELECT temp.*, 
  MATCH(name, descr) AGAINST ('$q') AS score
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM songs 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10000
    ) temp
WHERE MATCH (name, descr) AGAINST('$q') 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: That`s exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. Now I am getting this error: "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes", altough tables engine is MYISAM. Any any thoughts on that?

Comment: Um, are you _sure_ it's MyISAM for that table too?

Answer (score 0):

You can `ORDER BY score ASC` (instead of `DESC`) and add `LIMIT 10000` and finally reverse the order of the result :

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    MATCH(name, descr) AGAINST ('$q') AS score 
  FROM songs 
  WHERE MATCH (name, descr) AGAINST('$q') 
  ORDER BY score ASC
  LIMIT 10000
) ORDER BY score DESC
```