# MYSQL Getting reverse order limited by 6

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some games. How can I get the last 6 rows?
I've tried something with AUTO_INCREMENT to get last index and LIMIT but it doesn't work...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [select last N rows from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql)

Comment: @JohnConde Sorry Couldn't find it cause I didn't know how to formulate the question

Comment: That's ok. It happens. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
select * from `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Thanks, simple, fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6
```

Assuming autoincrement id.