# Sorting private messages the newest at the bottom

Tags: php, mysql

I have PM system and I want to be readble from the bottom to the top, also there is LIMIT 50 to be shown

The problem is if i order it by mess_id ASC it shows the first 50 resultd and if there are more they don't show.

If I order it by mess_id DESC it works but it then it shows the results at the top

[image]

I want the show the last 50 results and the last result to be at the bottom.
In the table there is also date field.
This is one of the codes

```
SELECT mess_id, message, mess_from_id, date FROM messages  ORDER BY mess_date DESC LIMIT 50
```

I'll be grateful if someone can help

Thanks in advance

Comment: So order by `mess_id DESC` and either read the result in reverse or save to an array and array_reverse/loop backwards over the array.

Comment: Why does it matter what order they are returned from the DB?  If you want to get the values in reverse, you can just write values to an array and iterate it in reverse.

Comment: After you retrieve the rows, use `array_reverse` on the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC
```

See this answer here: [Select last N rows from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql)

Comment: Yeah, that's better than my suggestion. The closest to the source the better.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "double order by":

```
select m.*
from (SELECT mess_id, message, mess_from_id, date
      FROM messages 
      ORDER BY mess_date DESC
      LIMIT 50
     ) m
order by mess_date ASC;
```