# mysql - select last two rows in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement that gets all the comments on a photo, and it is ordered so the first comment is at the top of the page:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post='$id' AND status='1' ORDER BY time
```

But I want to create a preview that only shows the 3 most recent comments.

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post='$id' AND status='1' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3
```

BUT I want these 3 comments to be in same order as the original comments, so the earliest comment is at the top. The above query puts the earliest comment at the bottom with the newest comment at the top. How do I maintain the same order by only get the three most recent comments?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post='$id' AND status='1' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3
) sub
ORDER BY time ASC
```

[MySQL Subquery Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)