# SQL: Select from n last rows; order by rand()

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to do "something" in MySQL. My plan is to pick the last 3 rows from a table where condition is like x. After that I want to pick one random row out of these 3 rows. I found something like that on here, tried it but that only gave me the overall-last row:

[Select last N rows from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql)

and here's how I tried to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM foo
    WHERE foo.row = 'bar'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 3) 
sub
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

thanks for the help!

/e:
all I get from it is the last row fitting my condition.
To be more specific: Users in my forums can "quote" other users - one of these quotes is shown randomly (out of all quotes) on the forums' index. Each time you enter the forums' index another quote is shown. Some users got (a lot) more quotes than others and to make it a bit fair I want to only pick a random quote out of the last three quotes by one user. It's SQL combined with PHP and the forums' software is MyBB.

So I want to pick one random quote out of the last three quotes by a specific user, which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM mybb_inplayquotes
    WHERE mybb_inplayquotes.uid = '$users[uid]'
    ORDER BY qid DESC
    LIMIT 3) sub
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

The result I get is always the same: the LAST row that fits my condition (so the Last Quote of User x); no error or something.

Comment: OK, and what happened when you tried this SQL? Did you get an error? The "wrong" result? Please [edit] the question to be as specific as you can. Ideally, give us some sample input and expected output, so that the question has a [mcve].

Comment: This looks correct. Keep in mind how hard it is to verify software designed to return random results. Try `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM ...` if you're testing this in a SQL client, to be sure MySQL runs the query again each time you try it. (It should do already: it should know `RAND()` isn't repeatable. But it might not.)

Comment: You could also try with a `LIMIT` larger than 3, as there will be less chance of getting repeated results when picking, say, 1 in 100 rather than 1 in 3.