# Select last rows from MySQL WordPress

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get last row with query to MySQL WordPress, The query is How much Post-Title with the title Germany each month, How can I reverse the result?

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT( p.id ) post_count, DATE_FORMAT( post_date,  '%Y-%m' ) post_month
FROM  `wp_posts` p
WHERE post_status =  'publish'
AND post_type = 'post'
AND post_title = 'Germany'
GROUP BY post_month
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Now result:

```
46 2023-03
130 2023-02
51 2023-01
```

I needed the reverse result:

```
51 2023-01
130 2023-02
46 2023-03
```

I try the sub-query from here : [Select last N rows from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql)

But nothing works.

Thanks guys

Getting reverse result to MySQL query on WordPress

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (... your select statement here...) ORDER BY id ASC`, But you do not have a column named `id`, so why are you using `ORDER BY` on it?     Try to use `ORDER BY post_month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order by date n ot by id

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`count_` int, `date_` varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`count_`, `date_`)
VALUES
    (46, '2023-03'),
    (130, '2023-02'),
    (51, '2023-01')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDEr By `date_`
```

| count_ | date_ |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 2023-01 |
| 130 | 2023-02 |
| 46 | 2023-03 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xVgLvVoS)

So use

```
SELECT COUNT( p.id ) post_count, DATE_FORMAT( post_date,  '%Y-%m' ) post_month
FROM  `wp_posts` p
WHERE post_status =  'publish'
AND post_type = 'post'
AND post_title = 'Germany'
GROUP BY post_month
ORDER BY post_month
LIMIT 3;
```

or use if the previous query  doesn't give you tee right answer

```
SELECT post_count, post_month
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT( p.id ) post_count, DATE_FORMAT( post_date,  '%Y-%m' ) post_month
    FROM  `wp_posts` p
    WHERE post_status =  'publish'
    AND post_type = 'post'
    AND post_title = 'Germany'
    GROUP BY post_month
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 3) t1
ORDER By post_month
```

Comment: And what if the first `post_date` in his data is somewhere in 2022 (or earlier) ?

Comment: @Luuk i add another solution

Comment: Thank You, But this query gave us the 3 first row and not the last

Comment: try the second one

Comment: Wow, that works perfect! just when we use LIMIT 5 is gave us the first 5 raw, when we execute without the LIMIT is gave us a good result but to much row. So there is away to get the only last row with LIMIT and not the first rows?

Answer (score 0):

From your expected result, it seems to me that you're trying to order by the `post_month` column in an ascending order.

So I think the query you're looking for is rather:

```
SELECT COUNT( p.id ) post_count, DATE_FORMAT( post_date,  '%Y-%m' ) post_month
FROM  `wp_posts` p
WHERE post_status =  'publish'
AND post_type = 'post'
AND post_title = 'Germany'
GROUP BY post_month
ORDER BY post_month ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Also here, Thank You, But this query gave us the 3 first row and not the last

Comment: @SQLNoob18 can you try the same query but instead of
`ORDER BY post_month ASC`, try `ORDER BY post_month DESC` ?

Comment: @EslamHossam see the comments on my answer,