# How to select only latest entries with IN clause?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with orders, with reoccuring order numbers per year:

```
create table orders (
    order_number varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    order_year year NOT NULL,
    ...
    primary key (order_number, order_year)
);
```

Data:

```
A111,2023,...
A111,2020,...
A222,2021,...
```

Now I want to select from a bunch of orders, but only take the ones with most recent `order_year`. But how?

The following query would of course select all orders from every year. How could I sort out everything but the latest year?

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_number IN ('A111', 'A222', ...);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125904/select-last-n-rows-from-mysql has answers for two options (sort result by order_year and sort by any other field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ytys2F4z)):

```sql
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders INNER JOIN (
  SELECT order_number, MAX(order_year) order_year 
  FROM orders 
  GROUP BY order_number
) x ON orders.order_number = x.order_number AND orders.order_year = x.order_year
```