# Selecting last rows of MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following code selects the last 10 rows from my table, but outputs them in reverse order because it's descending. How can i reverse that? Will I need to swap the array around in PHP or can this be done with the SQL statement?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10") ;
```

So how can I swap it around so I get the most recent row first from my selected 10?
This is more of a case of swapping the results around rather than getting last 10 rows, my code does that...

FIXED:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10) chat ORDER BY ID");
```

Comment: dupe dupe dupe ... see related column on the right...

Comment: bobster, it's better coding methodology to specify the column names rather than put the burden on the server to loop through all columns using *.

Comment: @Growler: it's not so much about the "burden on the server" (that's really a serious micro-optimisation), but more the effect of schema changes on code that expects a particular structure to the resultset.

Comment: @eggyal good to know. I'm still very new to the scene too :)

Comment: @eggyal btw How does * change the schema? Isn't "*" synonymous with a loop through all column names?

Comment: @eggyal I would think that each time you rename a column/change column order, '*' can just iterate through the newly presented dataset (update what it iterates over).

Comment: @Growler: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select

Comment: @bobster For new code it is better to use mysqli instead of mysql, because from php 5.5.0 onwards mysql is depreciated. See the manual for further reference http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10) t ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: " t ORDER BY ID" <-- Is that still SQL query?

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10") t ORDER BY ID ;
That's the line that gives an error.

Comment: Use the query from eggyal and change t into table_name, like so: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10) table_name ORDER BY ID

.

Comment: Now I get "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in posts.php on line 12"

Comment: Could inserting AS after LIMIT 10 help? "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10) AS t ORDER BY ID;" I think this question has some similarities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows

Comment: I'll add my PHP into my post now, hang on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function `array_reverse`, as described here: http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reverse.php