# Pulling last 10 orders from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to mysql and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way that you can pull information from the the last 5 most recent orders.

I'm trying to pull orderNumber, productName, and firstname for last 5 most recent orders.

I created 2 dummy tables that I'm working with:

Table:
    orders

Fields:
    orderNumber
    customerOid
    orderInformationOid
    purchaseDateTime

Table:
    customerData

Fields:
    customerOid
    firstName
    middleInitial
    lastName

Table:
    products

Fields:
    productOid
    productName
    companyOid

I was thinking an INNER JOIN but how to determine the most recent orders?

Comment: use `ORDER BY` eg. `ORDER BY purchaseDateTime` after the `WHERE` clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql select from n last rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY purchaseDateTime LIMIT 5;`

Comment: You seem to be missing an orderDetail table which has each product on the order. Then you would also be linking orders to orderDetail

Comment: Er, is that 5 or 10 ? !?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there's a `productOid` column in your orders table, then you can use this query:

```
SELECT o.orderNumber, p.productName, c.firstname
FROM
  (SELECT orderNumber, customerOid, productOid
   FROM orders
   ORDER BY purchaseDateTime DESC
   LIMIT 5) o
  INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customerOid = c.customerOid
  INNER JOIN products p ON o.productOid = p.productOid
```