# How to include current row(i.e last recent rows) in new database?

Tags: mysql

---

I want to insert last recent three rows in new database?

```
  +------------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------+------+--------------+
    | time       | userid   | groupid | jobs_running | jobs_pending | job_limit | 
    +------------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------+------+--------------+
    | 1476274005 | achandra |         |            4 |            0 |         0 |            
    | 1476274005 | akawle   |         |           52 |           48 |         0 |                    
    | 1476274005 | apatil2  |         |           20 |            6 |         0 |
    | 1476274793 | snagnoor |         |           17 |           67 |          0 |
    | 1476274793 | snatara2 |         |            0 |           54 |         0 |
    | 1476274793 | sthykkoo |         |            9 |          476 |         0 |
```

Expected Output:

```
        | 1476274793 | snagnoor |         |           17 |           67 |          0 |
        | 1476274793 | snatara2 |         |            0 |           54 |         0 |
        | 1476274793 | sthykkoo |         |            9 |          476 |         0 |
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows

Comment: what is the type of column `time`?

Comment: column time in seconda `date +%s` @Jagrati

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will work.
`db2` is new database and `db1` is old from where you have to copy the table

```
insert into db2.`new_table_name` select * from  db1.old_table order by `time` desc limit 3
```

ps. This code is untested.